# C++ cyclic dependency using class templates - how to refactor?

Tags: c++, templates, circular-dependency, extensible

I am dealing with a cyclic dependency problem in C++.

The situation looks like the following:

```
libA.so:
    - Body.cpp
    - Header.cpp
    - DataObject.cpp
    - DataObject::read(boost::asio::streambuf* data)
      {
          boost::asio::streambuf data;

          ....

          body = (new DataConverter<Body>)->convert(&data);
          header = (new DataConverter<Header>)->convert(&data);
      }

  libB.so:
      - DataConverter.cpp
          -> DataConverter<T>
          -> T* DataConverter<T>::convert(boost::asio::streambuf* data)

  libA.so <-> libB.so
```

There is a cyclic dependency because libA uses the Converter-Class from libB and libB needs to now about the Object-Types of libA that need to be converted - since DataConverter::convert returns a Body or Header object.

I thought about solving this issue with forward declarations - but that does not seem to be the cleanest solution to me. All in all my plan was to provide an extensible DataConverter solution.

What would you guys suggest as best practice? A complete different design is also welcome :)

Best,
Sebastian

Comment: That looks like a memory leak to me - you almost certainly want `DataConverter<Body>().convert(&data)`, with no `new` (unless `convert` ends with `delete this`, but that would be terrifying).

Comment: it was more pseudo code than anything else :)

Answer (score 8):

If you need a class template `DataConverter`, then this cannot be part of any compiled library. It has to be available via include files. Once you put the `DataConverter` code in a header, used by both `libA` and `libB` your cyclic dependency disappears.

Answer (score 3):

Your design seems to be flawed. If two libraries, named A and B, are dependent on each other, it means that they must always be shipped together. If they must always be shipped together, it means that they are logically part of the same interface. It means that in fact, you have only one library.

There is not enough information to tell what would be the best solution, but here are some tips:

1. Merge these libraries.
2. Make one library dependent on the other one, for example, by moving DataConverter to libA.
3. Create a utility library, dependent on these two.
4. Create an appropriate interface in libB, using templates or virtual classes, and make libA dependent on libB. The latter (virtual classes) is very likely to be a better choice in dynamically-linked library.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create abstract base classes defining the interface and hide the implementations (derived classes) from each other.

Comment: Ok - what about defining an AbstractConverter Factory that is actually returning the concrete Implementation for the specified templated target format. But how would that solve my dependency problem?

Comment: Define an abstract class containing all methods (abstract) a converter needs. You can do that in a header file. Include this header in the sources both of liba.so and of libb.so. The converters in libb derive (virtually, probably) from the abstract class. libb contains two factory methods returning converters, and these factory methods are declared as extern in liba. Thus libb knows about liba but liba does not now about libb.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives:

1. `DataConverter` as a fully generic implementation which will be instantianted in libA.so with proper types at compile time. This were a typical c++-ish solution. Your "convertable" types from libA (or others) would have to satisfy some `Convertable` concept which the fully templatized implementation of `DataConverter` would be using
2. Dependency inversion, as proposed by JohnB. You'd basically accomplish the same goal, but with interfaces, implementations and registration/resolving at runtime. A lot more of work to do, but scalable, ABI achievable, deployable as library etc...
3. Some kind of clever combination of both, something like `Boost.Serialization`. This is however difficult to achieve and easy to break...